# JUnit - ¿Puede un test bloquear el resultado de otro? ¿No son independientes?

Tags: junit, pruebas-unitarias, junit-4

Encuentro un problema con JUnit al crear un test que prueba un método según un valor, el cual funciona, pero si seguidamente creo otro test para el mismo método, pero pasándole otro valor, el anterior, que antes funcionaba, deja de hacerlo.

Este es el método en cuestión, se trata del constructor de la clase, el cual comprueba si la tabla que recibe como parámetro está vacía o es null:

```
TablaEnteros (Integer[] tabla) {
      if (tabla==null || tabla.length==0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("No hay elementos");
     this.tabla=tabla;
   }
```

Estas son las pruebas que realizo sobre el método, para comprobar si efectivamente se lanza la excepción al recibir la tabla vacía o null:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testIllegalArgumentExceptionConNull() {
    tabla = null;
    tablaEnteros = new TablaEnteros(tabla);
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testIllegalArgumentExceptionConCero() {
    tabla = new Integer[0];
    tablaEnteros = new TablaEnteros(tabla);
}
```

Y aquí mi duda. Al correr las pruebas, obtengo lo siguiente (ignorar los dos primeros resultados, son de otros métodos):

[image: Resultado primera prueba]

Se observa que la prueba con cero pasa correctamente, pero la de null, no. Sin embargo, si comento la del cero, que funcionaba en un principio, y dejo la del null, esta última si funciona:

[image: Resultado segunda prueba]

¿A que se debe esto? ¿Porqué la presencia de un test modifica el resultado de otro, acaso no son independientes?

Muchas gracias, y espero haber redactado bien la duda.

Comment: Se debe a que no liberas los recursos y los reutilizas, para ello usa las anotaciones que provee el api https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13.2/org/junit/After.html

Comment: Tal cual lo comenta el otro comentario, o liberas todo o inicializas todo para cada escenario.

Comment: @Ruslan López  Esa era la solución, muchas gracias.